# How to unfold a fold the cursor is in using modeline?

Tags: autocmd, folding, modeline

I've got automatic folding enabled in my file with the following `modeline`:

```
" vim:foldmethod=marker:foldlevel=0
```

I also have an autocmd like this to place the cursor where I left it:

```
if has("autocmd")
    au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
          \| exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

The problem is that if I left the cursor in the middle of a fold then my auto command will not work as desired.

What can I do to unfold the fold under the cursor on read, preferably using `modeline`?

I've tried adding `normal zv` to my autocmd but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set options with the modeline. You can't run Vimscript with it. This is for security reasons, because running code from random text files is not very good security.

The reason that running `normal zv` from the autocommand doesn't work is that the `BufReadPost` autocommand is run *before* the modeline is processed. From [`:help BufReadPost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufReadPost):

```
BufRead or BufReadPost          When starting to edit a new buffer, after
                                reading the file into the buffer, before
                                executing the modelines.  See BufWinEnter
                                for when you need to do something after
                                processing the modelines.
```

Luckily, it also provides a hint on how to proceed :-) Adding:

```
au BufWinEnter * normal! zv
```

Seems to work well.